# Finding the probability of drawing an even - ball at first & then odd-ball at second turn with replacement in a long way.

Tags: probability

> An urn contains 17 balls marked with the numbers 1 to 17. A ball is drawn at first & after replacing it a second ball is drawn. What is the probability that the first ball is even & the second one is odd?

The problem is quite easy. Let $$\begin{align}A = \text{event of getting even-numbered ball at the first draw} \\ B =\text{event of getting odd-numbered ball at the second draw} \end{align}$$. Then $P(A)= \dfrac{8}{17}\; \; \&\;\; P(B)= \dfrac{9}{17}$. So, $P(A\cap B)= P(A)\cdot P(B)= \dfrac{8\times 9}{17\times 17}= \dfrac{72}{289}$. This is the answer given by my book also.

However, I wanted to visualize the intersections between $A$ & $B$. Then $A$ would be the set $$A = \begin{align}\left\{ (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), \ldots (2, 17) \\ (4,1),(4,2), (4,3)(4,4),(4,5), \ldots (4,17) \\ (6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5)\ldots (6,17) \\\vdots \\ (16,1),(16,2),(16,3),(16,4),(16,5)\ldots (16, 17)\right\} \end{align}$$. Thus $A$ contains $17 \times 8$ elements. Similarly, $$B = \begin{align}\left\{(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)\ldots (17, 1) \\ (1,3),(2,3),(3,3), \ldots(17,3) \\ (1,5),(2,5),(3,5)\ldots (17,5) \\ \vdots \\ (1,17),(2,17),(3,17),\ldots (17,17)\right \}\end{align} $$ . Thus $B$ contains $17 \times 9$ elements.

Both contain $72$ elements in common as $\begin{align}\left\{(2,1),(2,3),(2,5)\ldots \text{9 elements} \\ (4,1),(4,3),(4,5) \ldots\text{9 elements}\ \\ \vdots \\ \text{8 rows containing 9 elements each }\\ \right \}\end{align}$.

So, the whole sample space $A \cup B$ should contain members $17 \times 8 + 17\times 9 - 72$. But this equals $217 \ne 289$ & that would contradict the probability of intersection as $P(A\cap B) = \dfrac{72}{217} \ne \dfrac{72}{289}$. That would mean I did wrong by deducting $72$ from $17 \times 8 + 17 \times 9$. But why? By counting,$17 \times 8 + 17 \times 9$, wouldn't I count $72$ elements common to $A\equiv (17 \times 8)$ & $B\equiv (17 \times 9)$ twice? So, why did I fail in this later approach? Why wouldn't I deduct $72$ from $A\cup B$?? Please help.

Comment: The sample space includes $(1,2)$, which is not in $A \cup B$

Comment: @Henry: So, the sample space is bigger than $A \cup B$ by 72 more elements more than to nullify the deduction of $72$, isn't it, sir?

Comment: Yes - though it is a different $72$ (the odd-evens rather rather than the even-odds)

Comment: @Henry: Thanks, sir; if I calculate $P(A \cap B)$ using the formula for compound probability, then also I get the same answer as I got by calculating $P(A)\cdot P(B)$: $$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B|A) =\frac{136}{289}\cdot \frac{72}{136} = \frac{72}{289}$$ . But $A$ & $B$ are independent events; so, how could the answer be same when I calculate by the formula of compound probability? The formula $P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$ is meant for dependent  variables. So, how could the answer be same then?

Comment: If they are independent then $P(B\mid A)=P(B)$ so it all works out nicely